# Don't see the Register and Login links after scaffolding Identity pages to an ASP .NET Core 6.0 MVC project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I am working on an Asp.Net Core 6.0 MVC project. I have scaffolded the Identity razor pages. I see all the razor pages being added correctly, including Register.chtml and Login.cshtml pages. The Program.cs file was also updated with the following lines

```
    builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<DbContext>();
        var app = builder.Build();

app.UseRouting();
    app.UseAuthentication(); 

    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.MapControllerRoute(
            name: "default",
            pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

When I run the application, I don't see the Register and Login links on the page. When I checked the Chrome Dev Tools, I don't see any JavaScript errors.

Comment: Scaffold again with new project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow this line was missing in the Program.cs file. Once, I added it, then I was able to see the Register and Login links

app.MapRazorPages();

Answer (score 0):

> don't see the Register and Login links

The Login link should appear in the layout part.

[image]

I think you can check if there's `<partial name="_LoginPartial" />` in your `_layout.cshtml`.

[image]

_LoginPartial.cshtml in the Shared folder:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
@inject SignInManager<IdentityUser> SignInManager
@inject UserManager<IdentityUser> UserManager

<ul class="navbar-nav">
@if (SignInManager.IsSignedIn(User))
{
    <li class="nav-item">
            @UserManager.FindByEmailAsync(@User.Identity?.Name).Result.PhoneNumber
        <a  class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Manage/Index" title="Manage">Hello @User.Identity?.Name!</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <form  class="form-inline" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Logout" asp-route-returnUrl="@Url.Action("Index", "Home", new { area = "" })">
            <button  type="submit" class="nav-link btn btn-link text-dark">Logout</button>
        </form>
    </li>
}
else
{
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Register">Register</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Login">Login</a>
    </li>
}
</ul>
```

By the way, if we use the asp.net core MVC template with authentication type `individual accounts`, the login part would be integrated automatically. We can then add scaffold for login/register page.

[image]